# What websock library does action cable use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Does Rails action cable use a custom websocket library or does it use an open source one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionCable uses the [Faye Websocket Driver](https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-ruby). You can find this information in the [Gemspec for ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/actioncable.gemspec#L24), which is available as part of the Rails project on Github.